# combining three different timestamp dataframes using duration match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three data frames with different dataframes and frequencies. I want to combine them into one dataframe.

First dataframe collects sunlight from sun as given below:

```
df1 = 
    index                 light_data
05/01/2019 06:54:00.000  10
05/01/2019 06:55:00.000  20
05/01/2019 06:56:00.000  30
05/01/2019 06:57:00.000  40
05/01/2019 06:59:00.000  50
05/01/2019 07:01:00.000  60
05/01/2019 07:03:00.000  70
05/01/2019 07:04:00.000  80
05/01/2019 07:06:00.000  90
```

Second dataframe collects solar power from unit-A

```
df2 = 
      index                   P1
    05/01/2019 06:54:24.000  100
    05/01/2019 06:59:32.000  200
    05/01/2019 07:04:56.000  300
```

Third dataframe collects solar power from unit-B

```
df3 = 
       index                  P2
    05/01/2019 06:56:45.000  400
    05/01/2019 07:01:21.000  500
    05/01/2019 07:06:34.000  600
```

Above three are measurements coming from the field. Three have different timestamps. Now I want to combine all three into data frame with one timestamp.

1. `df1` data occurs every minute
2. `df2` and `df3` occur every five minutes at different times.
3. Combine three data frames with `df2` timestamp as a reference index with no seconds information.

Finally, I want the output something like as given below:

```
df_combine =     
         combine_index        P1   light_data1    P2   light_data2
        05/01/2019 06:54:00  100     10          400       30
        05/01/2019 06:59:00  200     50          500       60
        05/01/2019 07:04:00  300     80          600       90
   # Note: combine_index is df2 index with no seconds
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question I am using `reindex` with `nearest` as method 1

```
df1['row']=df1.index
s1=df1.reindex(df2.index,method='nearest')
s2=df1.reindex(df3.index,method='nearest')
s1=s1.join(df2).set_index('row')
s2=s2.join(df3).set_index('row')

pd.concat([s1,s2.reindex(s1.index,method='nearest')],1)
Out[67]: 
                     light_data    A  light_data    B
row                                                  
2019-05-01 06:54:00          10  100          40  400
2019-05-01 06:59:00          50  200          60  500
2019-05-01 07:04:00          80  300          90  600
```

Or at the last line using `merge_asof`

```
pd.merge_asof(s1,s2,left_index=True,right_index=True,direction='nearest')
Out[81]: 
                     light_data_x    A  light_data_y    B
row                                                      
2019-05-01 06:54:00            10  100            40  400
2019-05-01 06:59:00            50  200            40  400
2019-05-01 07:04:00            80  300            90  600
```

---

Make it extendable

```
df1['row']=df1.index

l=[]
for i,x in enumerate([df2,df3]):
    s1=df1.reindex(x.index,method='nearest')
    if i==0:
        l.append(s1.join(x).set_index('row').add_suffix(x.columns[0].str[-1]))
    else :
        l.append(s1.join(x).set_index('row').reindex(l[0].index,method='nearest').add_suffix(x.columns[0].str[-1]))
pd.concat(l,1)
```

Comment: Presently I am executing your code. At this line `s1=dfpoa.reindex(dfm1.index,method='nearest')` I got this error. `TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'`. Any guess about what could be wrong?

Comment: make sure all df , index is datetime type, like `df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Comment: Great! thanks for the quick response. I realized my mistake. One of index was a string. Now converted. It is working perfectly as I wanted. You are just great. I am new to python. I did not expect that my question was easy to crack. You did it. Great. I have a last question. I am actually collecting data from 24 power plants. Is it possible to combine 24 data frames using one line as in your answer?

Comment: how to name those columns unique in `combine_df`. That is, `A_light_data`, `B_light_data` something like that

Comment: I got the update. As I understood, this is where `enumerate([df2,df3])` my 24 dataframes would fit like `enumerate([df2,df3,df4,..............,df24])` . Am i right?

Comment: I have no more questions to ask you. You are really great. Internet is making everything possible for me. Thanks a lot for your patience to answer questions from a newcomer like me. It is a good encouragement.

Comment: I just updated my question to include numerical in column names instead of A, B. Could you change for loop in your code accordingly. So I can use it for my 24 data frames.

Comment: @Msquare check again

Comment: Thanks for updating your post. I just compiled it. Got some error `ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit` for this line `l.append(s1.join(x).set_index('time').reindex(l[0].index,method='nearest').add_suffix(x.columns[0][-1]))`. Any idea what could be wrong here? I got another error before to this related to `add_suffix(x.columns[0].str[-1])` saying `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`. I changed it to `add_suffix(x.columns[0][-1])`.

Comment: @Msquare the error means your index have duplicate try remove it

Comment: could you elaborate more what this means? and how do I remove duplicate? Here is complete code: ` l = [ ]
    for i,x in enumerate([dfm1,dfm2,dfm24]):
        s1=dfpoa.reindex(x.index,method='nearest')
        if i==0:
            l.append(s1.join(x).set_index('time').add_suffix(x.columns[0][-1]))
        else :
            l.append(s1.join(x).set_index('time').reindex(l[0].index,method='nearest').add_suffix(x.columns[0][-1]))
    combdf = pd.concat(l,1)`

Comment: @Msquare I think that is all I can do , you may need to find the duplicate by using https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Comment: @ WeNYoBen Main light_df had some missing timestamps. The program could not run as remaining dataframes had more timestamps. I got it solved. Thanks

Comment: @Msquare that is great then :-) since we usually do not have the real data , so the best we can do is given the idea :-)

Comment: could you please check my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211510/python-combining-26-dataframes-of-different-timestamps-and-same-columns

Comment: @Msquare check the answer

Comment: It worked as I wanted. Excellent. Thank you very much for help.