# Merge two dataframes on closest matching datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

I have two data frames with closest matching DateTime index, sometimes matching. The object is to merge two of them using one index as a reference and appending the second to the closest matching  (within 1 minute) on the first one.

My code and output:

```
import pandas as pd

masterdf = pd.DataFrame({"AA":[77.368607,77.491655,77.425134,76.490991]})
masterdf.index = ['2019-10-01 07:52:07','2019-10-01 07:53:01','2019-10-01 07:53:54','2019-10-01 07:54:47']
masterdf.index.name = 'datetime'

slavedf = pd.DataFrame({"BB":[50,60,70,80]})
slavedf.index = ['2019-10-01 07:53:00','2019-10-01 07:53:54','2019-10-01 10:54:47','2019-10-01 10:00:00']
slavedf.index.name = 'datetime'

maindf = masterdf.merge(slavedf,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

Presentoutput:

```
masterdf = 
                            AA
datetime                      
2019-10-01 07:52:07  77.368607
2019-10-01 07:53:01  77.491655
2019-10-01 07:53:54  77.425134
2019-10-01 07:54:47  76.490991

slavedf = 
                     BB
datetime               
2019-10-01 07:53:00  50
2019-10-01 07:53:54  60
2019-10-01 10:54:47  70
2019-10-01 10:00:00  80

maindf = 
datetime                   AA         BB
2019-10-01 07:53:54    77.425134      60
```

Expected output:

```
maindf = 
datetime                   AA          BB
2019-10-01 07:53:01    77.491655       50
2019-10-01 07:53:54    77.425134       60
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: @BEN_YO can you help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC I have modified it. I am sure you should be able to reproduce the same at your end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic here use the `merge_asof` , we need to adjust it due to , `merge_asof` will use the 2nd dataframe mutiple times , then we need additional key here is datetime to drop the duplicate

```
masterdf.index=pd.to_datetime(masterdf.index)
masterdf=masterdf.sort_index().reset_index()
slavedf.index=pd.to_datetime(slavedf.index)
slavedf=slavedf.sort_index().reset_index()
slavedf['datetime2']=slavedf['datetime']
slavedf['key']=slavedf.index
newdf=pd.merge_asof(masterdf,slavedf,on='datetime',tolerance=pd.Timedelta('60s'),direction='nearest')
newdf['diff']=(newdf.datetime-newdf.datetime2).abs()
newdf=newdf.sort_values('diff').drop_duplicates('key')
newdf
Out[35]: 
             datetime         AA  BB           datetime2     diff
2 2019-10-01 07:53:54  77.425134  60 2019-10-01 07:53:54 00:00:00
1 2019-10-01 07:53:01  77.491655  50 2019-10-01 07:53:00 00:00:01
```

Comment: Wow. Excellent. You just nailed it. Thanks a ton. I have been banging my head for hours to get this. You are spot on. I just have a couple of questions. My actual dataframe has 20,000 rows. I really appreciate the `newdf['diff']` that you created to see the time difference between the merged rows. I see a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 7s difference. My question is: `drop_duplicates('key')` drops what kind of rows?

Comment: @Mainland same B assign to diff row in A , you only want to keep the lowest time diff ~

Comment: What you are saying is, there is a chance that one row value in B could get assigned to two or more rows in A? so that time difference is put to low? Am I right?

Comment: @Mainland since i set the tolerance as 1 min , if you set it low, we can reduce the change of getting same B row assign to multiple A row

Comment: I just wanted what you thought of that is keeping minimum time difference. Nothing more. Even I was worried that what kind of value get assigned to which row? I cannot check each of them manually. Your new column and sorting, did help me to understand the kind of time difference we are talking about. I was really amazed. Thanks ton.

Comment: @Mainland yw :-) happy coding ~

Comment: yw :-) Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clarify some things regarding "closest matching DateTime Index"

Is it both ways match?
What about elements that already used?
Are there any limitations of the differences between indexes?

If you clarify these, the task can be solved

Comment: I have updated my question. About 1 minute closest match is fine. I have not understood your remaining questions.

Comment: By 'both ways' i mean if Ax can be larger and smaller than his match Bx 

The rest question means that if for example element Bx was used for another match, can it be used again or not?

Comment: Yes! in the above problem, `slavedf` has more rows than `masterdf`.