# combining three dataframes with matching timestamps and duration match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Note: This question is some similar to the answered question here [combining three different timestamp dataframes using duration match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56980740/combining-three-different-timestamp-dataframes-using-duration-match)

I have two master and one slave data frame. The two master data frames data occurs for every 30 minutes.  I am combining three data frames with masters as a reference and matching timestamps from the slave as given below. Data of two masters taken during a particular session should appear in a single row.

**My input** is

```
mas_df1 = 
        index           S1
2019-01-09 13:20:17  2202.517620
2019-01-09 14:00:17  2392.173558

mas_df2 = 
        index           S2
2019-01-09 13:24:32  2134.791454
2019-01-09 14:04:32  1958.719125

mas_list  = [mas_df1,mas_df2]

slv_df = 
   index                  POA      
2019-01-09 13:20:00    752.743700
2019-01-09 13:20:17    742.961815
2019-01-09 13:24:32    697.267647
2019-01-09 13:24:48    699.418420
2019-01-09 14:00:00    778.720800
2019-01-09 14:00:17    791.852790
2019-01-09 14:04:32    691.605547
2019-01-09 14:04:48    688.313520
```

The combined data frame should have timestamps and complete data of both masters.  But, only the data of slave df should append to it at matching timestamps.

**My present code** to achieve this is given below.

```
aux = []
for i in range(0,len(mas_list),1):
    s1=slv_df['POA'].reindex(mas_list[i].index,method='nearest').add_prefix(mas_list[i].columns[0])  
    if i==0:
        aux.append(s1.join(mas_list[i]))
    else:
        aux.append(s1.join(mas_list[i]).reindex(aux.index,method='nearest'))
cmb_df = pd.concat(aux,axis=1)
```

**My present output** is:

```
raise ValueError("cannot reindex a non-unique index "

ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit
```

**My expected output** is:

```
cmd_df = 
        index           S1              S1POA        S2               S2POA
2019-01-09 13:20:17  2202.517620     742.961815     2134.791454    697.267647 
2019-01-09 14:00:17  2392.173558     791.852790     1958.719125    691.605547
```

Any suggestions to improve my code?

Comment: i would use df.merge() rather than concat().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import pandas as pd

# create dataframes
mas_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'S1': [2202.517620, 2392.173558]}, index=pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-09 13:20:17', '2019-01-09 14:00:17']))
mas_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'S2': [2134.791454, 1958.719125]}, index=pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-09 13:24:32', '2019-01-09 14:04:32']))
slv_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'POA': [752.743700, 742.961815, 697.267647, 699.418420, 778.720800, 791.852790, 691.605547, 688.313520]},
    index = pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-09 13:20:00', '2019-01-09 13:20:17', '2019-01-09 13:24:32', '2019-01-09 13:24:48',
                            '2019-01-09 14:00:00', '2019-01-09 14:00:17', '2019-01-09 14:04:32', '2019-01-09 14:04:48'])
)


# combine slave to master (i.e. left join per master df)
mas_df1 = mas_df1.merge(slv_df, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True).rename(columns={'POA': 'S1PAO'})
mas_df2 = mas_df2.merge(slv_df, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True).rename(columns={'POA': 'S2PAO'})

# combine two master dataframes, by matching to the nearest time
mas_df2 = mas_df2.reindex(mas_df1.index, method='nearest')  # set index of df2 to match (nearest) index of df1
mas_df = pd.concat([mas_df1, mas_df2], axis=1)  # comnine dataframe

mas_df
```

**EDIT: doing the same for a list of dataframes**

```
# combine slave to master (i.e. left join per master df)
mas_list  = [mas_df1, mas_df2]
for i, df in enumerate(mas_list):
    mas_list[i] = df.merge(slv_df, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True).rename(columns={'POA': f'S{i}PAO'})


# combine master dataframes, by matching to the nearest time of the first master frame
for i, df in enumerate(mas_list[1:]):
    mas_list[i+1] = df.reindex(mas_list[0].index, method='nearest')   # set index of mas dfs > 1 to match (nearest) index of df1

mas_df = pd.concat(mas_list, axis=1)  # comnine dataframe
```

Comment: What if I have more than two master dfs? Can it be put in a loop? Thanks

Comment: Code could possibly be a little cleaner, but this should do it.

Comment: I tried it but got the following error while executing second part of your code that is combining master dataframes by matching to the nearest time of the first master frame. `raise ValueError("cannot reindex a non-unique index "

ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit`. In between, the first part of the code did work very well.

Comment: That suggests there are duplicate timestamps in one of your >second master dataframes. Could you please check with `mas_dfX.groupby(mas_dfX.index).count().sort_values('SX', ascending=False)` (where X is the xth master df).

Also, **please note** that the current approach **assumes certain consistency** in the timestamps between the master dataframes. df.reindex(method='nearest') will try to match each row of master dfx to the timestamps of master df1. However, if dfx has more than one row to match to a single row of df1, you might get unwanted behaviour (e.g. rows left out from dfx).